# How to display subtotals for a main and sub category of a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have the following data:

[image]

I want to calculate the occurrence of each color for a given shape.

Using PivotTables, I got this:

[image]

However, this is the output I want:

[image]

How do I achieve this in Excel? Is this possible using a PivotTable?

Thanks!

Comment: If you put Shape first and colour second in rows, then count of colour in values. You'll get basically this layout - but with the totals first (due to the way that Pivot tables group and summarize)

Comment: You can move the totals to the bottom, see my below answer.

Comment: Can I use the PivotTable to count the number of colors that each shape has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Yes, it is.

(1) Structure your selected fields like this:

[image]

(2) Right click "Shape" in Row Labels and in the "Layout & Print" tab, select "Show item labels in tabular form".

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nhee! I just wanted to know if I can I use the PivotTable to count the number of colors that each shape has? For example - Circle has 3 distinct colors and Square has 2.

Comment: Ok. Well unfortunately, PivotTables cannot count unique values (even though is a frequently asked-for feature) so you will need to count manually or semi-automatically using `COUNTIFS` formulas.